# Can I call ajax function inside another ajax function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, html

I am using jquery for getting ajax responses from server side functions.

I am in a situation where I need to make two ajax calls one after another and the second one is dependent on the response of the first one.

I have tried to use a code which is similar to this one?

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'myURL',
        success: function(data1)
        { 
               if(data1==1)
               {
                   $.get('newURL', function(data2)
                   { 
                       $('#myElement').html(data2);
                   });
                   $('#myElement').html(data1);
               }
        }
});
```

Is it possible to get two have two ajax calls , one dependent on the other?

if it's possible please explain with demo code . i am new in jquery

Thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: Yes, that's possible, and you'd do it just like that.

Comment: When you tried it, did it work?

Comment: Did you try it? Did you hit any errors?

Comment: You have already told us demo in your question, just add a `url` in your `$.get` and see whats happening. add some param and print it in your provided urls file function.